# Double-clicking a vote button on a proposed question for a site already in beta creates an unclosable notification box

Tags: bug, area-51

If you go to the definition page for a site already in beta (e.g. [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science?phase=definition&tab=votes#tab-top)) and double-click on the voting button, a notification box shows up that cannot be closed by clicking the "cancel" button.

[image: unclosable box]

The box still goes away (and is replaced by another box at the appropriate location) if you click on a different voting button, though.

My browser is Chrome 34 on Windows 7. I don't see any errors in the JS console.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah, yup. That'll do it.

Comment: Too bad this won't be fixed though.